# Mint 17: Kaffeine Time-Shift

Tags: linux, linux-mint, tv

I switched from Windows 7 to Linux Mint 17. Under Windows 7 I used `ProgDvb` to watch TV and now I use `Kaffeine`. What I miss is a similar time-shift function that is why I this three questions:

1. Can time-shift be per default activated without always to click the pause button?
2. After clicking the pause button I can not use the bar to select a certain position. How can I accomplish this?
3. Can I set a certain file with a fixed size to be stored in?

Thanks for your help

Comment: when i last used kaffeine about 5 years ago you could set a file to store the timeshift in, i will see if i can find the instructions for it, as for the first 2 questions i have no idea

Comment: There is a timeshift script for this on sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/projects/timeshift/